# Disable download as PPT or PDF to allow only a 'preview' of a presentation on Google Drive

Tags: powerpoint

To run a PPT file on the web via Google Drive. Also don't allow any visitor to download or print the PDF file. It must allow the user to view that file only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on *[Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Upload PPT file on Google Drive.

Click on share button:

[image]

Click on below checkbox to restrict user to download PPT:

[image]

Go to File menu and click on "**publish to web**"

[image]

Select Options and Time interval for slider show and click on "**publish**" button

[image]

Share below link with any one to whom you want to show PPT:

[image]

Uploading PPT by this method will restrict visitor to download or print the PPT file.